# Directive within a directive within a template not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm an Angular noob. I'm structuring my panes as sets of tables and using directives to keep the template HTML abstract from the table implementation. The panes are getting transcluded correctly, but interior only contains the text not the table structure. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src= "angular.js"></script>
<script src= "angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="pp">

<div ng-controller="ppMain">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="pageID in homePageList">{{pages[pageID].str}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="pageID in pageList" ng-bind-html="pages[pageID].template">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

var pp = {
    ctl: {}
};

pp.mod = angular.module('pp', ['ngSanitize']);
pp.mod.directive({
    'ppHeader': function () {
        return ({
        });
    },
    'ppGroup': function () {
        return ({
            template: '<table ng-transclude></table>',
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'EA'
        });
    },
    'ppRow': function () {
        return ({
            template: '<tr ng-transclude></tr>',
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'EA'
        });
    },
    'ppLabel': function () {
        return ({
            template: '<td ng-transclude></td>',
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'EA'
        });
    },
    'ppValue': function () {
        return ({
            template: '<td ng-transclude></td>',
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'EA'
        });
    },
});
pp.ctl.main = pp.mod.controller('ppMain', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.curPage = 'page1';
    $scope.pages = {
        "page1": {
            str: "page 1",
            template:'\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>1</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '},
        "page2": {
            str: "page 2",
            template:'\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>2</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '},
        "page3": {
            str: "page 3",
            template:'\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>3</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '}
    };
    $scope.pageList = ["page1","page2","page3"];
    $scope.homePageList = ["page2", "page3"];

}]);


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the generated DOM with the debugger, I find no tables, only text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with `ng-bind-html` because ng-sanitize does not compile the html. It can only be used for static content. You would need to create a directive yourself for this.

Something like this:

```
.directive('compileHtml', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var template = scope.$eval(attrs.compileHtml); //get the template by evaluating
      elm.html(template); //set the html
      $compile(elm.contents())(scope); //compile the contents
    }
  }
});
```

Also remember that you have child directives with no replace, which means you will be creating invalid html, `table` created by `ppGroup` will have `ppRow` as child which results in invalid html and it will push the directive content out of the table and compilation will not happen properly. So you would instead need to use the option `replace:true` on these directives.

*However it will be really unsafe to compile the html dynamically though unless you know it is from a trusted source which is what `$sce` service used by `ng-bind-html` does. It sanitizes the boundhtml.*

**Demo**

```js
var pp = {
  ctl: {}
};

pp.mod = angular.module('pp', ['ngSanitize']);

pp.mod.directive({
  'ppHeader': function() {
    return ({});
  },
  'ppGroup': function() {
    return ({
      template: '<table ng-transclude></table>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'EA'
    });
  },
  'ppRow': function() {
    return ({
      replace: true,
      template: '<tr ng-transclude></tr>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'EA'
    });
  },
  'ppLabel': function() {
    return ({
      replace: true,
      template: '<td ng-transclude></td>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'EA'
    });
  },
  'ppValue': function() {
    return ({
      replace: true,
      template: '<td ng-transclude></td>',
      transclude: true,
      restrict: 'EA'
    });
  },
}).directive('compileHtml', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var template = scope.$eval(attrs.compileHtml);
      elm.html(template);
      $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
});
pp.ctl.main = pp.mod.controller('ppMain', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.curPage = 'page1';
    $scope.pages = {
      "page1": {
        str: "page 1",
        template: '\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>1</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '
      },
      "page2": {
        str: "page 2",
        template: '\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>2</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '
      },
      "page3": {
        str: "page 3",
        template: '\
                <pp-group>\
                    <pp-row>\
                        <pp-label>Page:</pp-label><pp-value>3</pp-value>\
                    </pp-row>\
                </pp-group>\
            '
      }
    };
    $scope.pageList = ["page1", "page2", "page3"];
    $scope.homePageList = ["page2", "page3"];

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="pp">

  <div ng-controller="ppMain">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li ng-repeat="pageID in homePageList">{{pages[pageID].str}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="pageID in pageList" compile-html="pages[pageID].template">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks. The actual DOM elements for the table don't seem to have spurious elements. I'd love to use replace, because I think that's what's called for, but the docs say that replace is deprecated and will be removed. Do you have any ideas about a way to get clean HTML without replace?

Comment: @srkleiman Yes replace option has been deprecated but not removed yet. However the other way to do it is with attributes. The problem with your directive is that it does not have a self standing html. i.e you cannot really use your directives as is. You need them combined. You could as well combine them to one directive. I believe one of the reasons for the deprecation is to enforce semantically correct markup to be injected to DOM.